# Split a string into words which are enclosed in single quotes

Tags: tcl

I want to split a string into separate words which which are enclosed in single quotes like below:

For example:

```
set str {'Name' 'Karna Mayer' ''}
```

I want to split this into 3 separate words. How can this be performed using Tcl.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For this sort of task, I'd use `regexp -all -inline` and `lmap` (to drop the unwanted bits from the results of that).

```
set input "'Name' 'Karna Mayer' ''"
set output [lmap {- bit} [regexp -all -inline {'([^'']*)'} $input] {set bit}]
```

The good thing about this is that if you have a way of escaping a single quote in that, you can use a more complex regular expression and match that too.

```
set output [lmap {- bit} [regexp -all -inline {'((?:\\.|[^''])*)'} $input] {
    string map {\\ {}} $bit
}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use string map to convert the single quotes to double quotes and escape existing quotes

```
set str [string map {{"} {\"} ' {"}} $str]
# "name" "Karna Mayer" ""
```

you can then use `list` and argument expansion to convert it to a list

```
set l [list {*}$str]
# Name {Karna Mayer} {}
```

full program

```
set str {'Name' 'Karna Mayer' ''}
set str [string map {{"} {\"} ' {"}} $str]
set l [list {*}$str]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use single quote as a separator, then you'll take every *second* element:

```
% set input "'Name' 'Karna Mayer' ''"
'Name' 'Karna Mayer' ''
% split $input {'}
{} Name { } {Karna Mayer} { } {} {}
```

We see: the empty string before the first quote; the first field; the space between the 1st and 2nd; the 2nd field; the next space; the (empty) 3rd field; and then the empty string after the last quote. We want to ignore this last element.

```
% set fields [lmap {_ field} [lrange [split $input {'}] 0 end-1] {set field}]
Name {Karna Mayer} {}
```

No thanks to the Tcl syntax highlighter.